# Number of numeric values present in NVarchar column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a Nvarchar column which contains data related to different data types such as Numerics, Dates and so on.
I wanted to find out number of cells with Numeric data type and number of cells with Date data type.

Thanks

Comment: Would `'20041201'` be counted as both?

Comment: No.It should be counted as date.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want IsDate() and IsNumeric():

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN IsDate(DataColumn) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dates,
    Sum(CASE WHEN IsNumeric(DataColumn) = 1 AND IsDate(DataColumn) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Numbers
FROM YourTable
```

This is assuming that you have a single date format, and that that format is supported by SQL Server's dateformat option. To define the correct format, you would use `SET DateFormat`. See [MSDN Documentation on IsDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx).

You mention that '20041201' could be a valid date, which is why I added the extra IsDate() check in the numeric count (I assume you wouldn't want to count it as both a date and a number).

Answer (score 0):

First at all you should split you column (create split function which will transform delimited string into column) . You can find a lot of examples in Internet. I have got one [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx) . So here is an example:

```
declare @text nvarchar(max)='1211221,ssssss,1212,2010-02-01,20100201'
DECLARE @delimiter char(1)=','
 ;WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT CASt(1 as Int), CAST(1 as integer), CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@text)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, CAST(stop + 1 as integer), CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@text, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    ), T as(
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@text, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces)
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(T.s)=1 AND ISDATE(T.s)=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumericCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISDATE(T.s)=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)DateCount 
FROM T
```

You will have 2 dates and 2 numeric counts